# Is $-a-b=0$ equivalent to $ 0 = a+b $ therefore to $a + b = 0 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $-a-b=0$ equivalent to $ 0 = a+b $ therefore to $a + b = 0 $?

Does it really work that way? It seems a bit fishy

ex : $-2 -(-2) =0 \iff 2 + (-2) = 0$

It seems to work. But does it always work?

Comment: Sure. Alternatively, just multiply both sides of the original equation by $-1$.

Comment: Yes; equality is [symmetrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) : if $a=b$, then $b=a$.

Comment: The answer **totally depends** on what all those symbols are. You didn't define any of them. It is not hard to define not symmetrical "$=$" and even easier to define unrelated "$-$" and "$+$". Are you talking about integers with their natural operators here?

Comment: what about unknown a and b but different that satisfies the equation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we have

\begin{align*}
-a-b&=0\\
\underline{+a+b}&=\underline{+a+b}\\
0&=a+b
\end{align*}
And yes, if $0$ is the sum of two numbers, then the sum of two numbers is $0$, i.e. if $0=a+b$, then $a+b=0$.